# How can I have a user attach a file to a workflow task?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer, custom, tasks, attachments

I'm using sharepoint designer 2010, custom list.
I have created workflow on that list.

I need to enable the user to enclose a file to the workflow task:

What kind of task I need to use?

P.S.
I'm not using infopath.

Comment: I'm afraid this part doesn't make sense to me, could you rephrase it, please? "I need to feasible the user to attached file"

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use a document library instead of a custom list? Why would a user attach the document to the workflow task?

Comment: I am looking for the same thing. So far I came across the following MSDN social blog, but am continuing to look. Will let you know if I find another answer.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepoint2010general/thread/1d23460e-a9d2-414f-95ed-b0b15e21d814